# how to pass jquery date parameters in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Please help me.. I have the following codes..

```
             //Get the value of Start and End of Week
            $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
            var value = $("#weeklyDatePicker").val();
            var firstDate = moment(value, "MM/DD/YYYY").day(0).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
            var lastDate =  moment(value, "MM/DD/yyyy").day(6).format("MM/DD/YYYY");

            $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(firstDate + " - " + lastDate);

            });
```

now I want to pass the firstDate and the lastDate to a php. How should I do this. and how can I retrieve the passed value in the php. I'm not very familiar with javascripts. Hope anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is my full code..
JS tags

```
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
 <div class="input-group" id="DateDemo">
<input type='text' id='weeklyDatePicker' placeholder="Select Week" class="form-control" />
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
```

JS

```
 $("#weeklyDatePicker").datetimepicker({
            calendarWeeks:true,
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'

            });

            //Get the value of Start and End of Week
            $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
            var value = $("#weeklyDatePicker").val();
            var firstDate = moment(value, "MM/DD/YYYY").day(0).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
            var lastDate =  moment(value, "MM/DD/yyyy").day(6).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
            $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(firstDate + " - " + lastDate);
            alert(firstDate);
            $.post("SAMPLE1.php",{"fdate" : firstDate ,"ldate" : lastDate});
            });


            $('#DateDemo').on('dp.change', function (e) {
            var kk = $("#weeklyDatePicker").val();
             $("#output").html(
            "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Week Number: " + moment(kk, "MM/DD/YYYY").week() + " of " + 
            moment(kk, "MM/DD/YYYY").weeksInYear()
            );
            });
```

SAMPLE1 CODE

```
 <?php
 echo $_POST["fdate"]; //for firstdate
 echo $_POST["ldate"]; //for lastdate
 ?>
```

Comment: Use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: There are 2 options: 1) Use `ajax` 2) set the value to be sent in `input type hidden` and when form is submitted, you can access that value in `$_POST`/`$_GET`

Comment: can you show me how to code it? Thanks also for answering @Tushar

Comment: Try [this](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20submit%20a%20form%20in%20php) or [this](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20use%20ajax%20in%20php)

Comment: simple example [ajax](http://brian.staruk.me/php/2013/sample-jquery-php-ajax-script/)

Comment: @KathDee do you have any intention to return to the page which has the javascript and posts the data to your PHP? Or is the second page (your PHP script) where everything will be finalized? Because if this is the case, you should not use AJAX for that.

Comment: @ArmanOzak Not exactly sir. the code above, I just wanna check if the firstDate and lastDate can be read  or retrieved in the second page. but my intention to be exact is that I want to make a query in the second page depending on the firstDate and LastPage that is sent by the first page.

Comment: @KathDee ok, but do you need to turn back to the first page after this is done?

Comment: @ArmanOzak yes sir.. I just want to know if the query has ben done successfully.

Comment: OK. then you need to use AJAX. `jQuery.ajax()` is a good way to do it. I will add an answer covering that in a few minutes.

Comment: thank you for answering sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `$.ajax()` function, which will let you handle the error status as well, because it is both a good practice to handle errors for the users and an indicator of what is going wrong with your script.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {fdate : firstDate ,ldate : lastDate},
    dataType: 'text',
    beforeSend: function(){
        // initiate some spinner or loading infobox
        // to inform the user about the AJAX request
    },
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
        // you may use result like any standard argument
        // and call or trigger other functions according to its value
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        // call some error handler or do nothing
    },
    complete: function(){
        // close the spinner or loading box
    }
});
```

In your PHP file, you get the variables as `$_POST['fdate']` and `$_POST['lDate']`. Once you complete the query and get the results, `echo` a response something like that:

```
echo 'success';
```

or

```
echo 'failure';
```

according to the result of the query. You may use any string, not just success or failure. Just **don't forget that is what you will handle in the `success` part** of your `$.ajax()` function and not the `error` part of it. The `error` part is only for whatever goes wrong with the request (e.g. file not found or server error).

Well, here is the tricky part: If the only thing you want to return is a status, you may use `dataType: 'text'` in your `$.ajax()` function as I did in this example. However, if you want to return an object with some useful data, such as what has gone wrong with the PHP query or what has been accomplished by the PHP query, then you'd better to use `dataType: 'json'` and get a JSON response. In such a case, the end of your PHP script will change too.

```
$result = ['statusCode'=>1,'details'=>'Some details according to the query here'];
echo json_encode($result);
```

The success handler of your `$.ajax()` function will get an object as the argument (i.e. `response` will be an object) which you can use like this:

```
alert(response.statusCode); // will alert 1
```

Comment: sir can I echo $_POST['fdate'] and $_POST['lDate']? just to see what their values are?

Comment: You cannot see the results of your PHP script (even if you do nothing but echo) directly. To see those values use the second method I explained above (dataType: 'json') and alert or console.log them in your JavaScript using the response object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery for that. Try this code :

YOUR JS FILE CODE :

```
$('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
     var value = $("#weeklyDatePicker").val();
     var firstDate = moment(value, "MM/DD/YYYY").day(0).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
     var lastDate =  moment(value, "MM/DD/yyyy").day(6).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
     $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(firstDate + " - " + lastDate);

     $.post("main.php",{fdate : firstDate ,ldate : lastDate},function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

YOUR PHP FILE CODE (main.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["fdate"])) {
   echo $_POST["fdate"]; //for firstdate
}
if(isset($_POST["ldate"])) {
    echo $_POST["ldate"]; //for lastdate
}
?>
```

Make sure both the files are in same folder.

Comment: hi ! I tried your code.. but I've got an error, "Uncaught ReferenceError: firstDate is not defined" Does $.post should be placed outside the $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function (e) ??

Comment: I tried it but it only says, "Notice: Undefined index: fdate" and "Notice: Undefined index: ldate" even after I chose a date interval..

Comment: Try this : `$.post("test.php",{"fdate" : firstDate ,"ldate" : lastDate},function(data) {alert(data)});`

Comment: does this matter? I just placed my php code together with my html code. so I replaced the "test.php" to my "main.php".

Comment: I have move my php code to another php file which is the test.php. but still it is not workin. :(

Comment: that's why its not working.See I've updated my answer according to your requirements.

Comment: from the console Log, I see it was sent but it is not echoed in php. I mean it does not show the date after I click or chose a date.

Comment: i have added the sample1 above. sorry i missed it awhile ago

Comment: There is no error in the console.. it says "XHR finished loading: POST"

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is probably the easiest.

Javascript:

```
$.get("test.php", { firstDate: firstDate, lastDate: lastDate } );
```

or

```
$.post("test.php", { firstDate: firstDate, lastDate: lastDate } );
```

and in php

```
<?php
    echo $_REQUEST['firstDate'];
    echo $_REQUEST['lastDate'];
?>
```

Comment: Hi I also tried your code. It only returns "undefined index: firstDate", same as the code above. what should be the problem??

Comment: There must be a different issue. This fiddle works: https://jsfiddle.net/mayko/8oxnr13c/

Comment: In your fiddle, what is suppose to happen? i have chosen a date in a dropbox then nothing happened?

Comment: You should open the consoles network tab and you will see the requests going out.

Comment: it says GET 404(NOT FOUND) ??

Comment: Thats because the test.php does not exist on jsfiddle, but you can see that the url includes a firstDate parameter and the value which you can access via php on your own server.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Kath Dee please check below code, I hope solve your problem using below code.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
        // I am using test value, you can change var value base on id.
        var firstDate =  '08/02/2016';
        var lastDate  =  '10/02/2016';

        //$("#weeklyDatePicker").val(firstDate + " - " + lastDate);
         $.post("test.php",{fdate : firstDate ,ldate : lastDate},function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(data);
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" value="" id="weeklyDatePicker" />
```

test.php

```
<?php 
    // set your format as you want for display.
    echo $_POST['fdate'].'-'.$_POST['ldate'];
?>
```

I hope this is working fine for you.

Comment: the display is not working. it is passing the value of first date and llast date but it is not showing/echoed in php ..

Comment: Kath can you please shear your code so I can check.

Comment: Hi Kath do one things, 
 Create one directory, in this directory create two file 1.index.php 2.test.php  add above code in this file and run index.php, directory must put in your xampp/wamp  server. I hope you got the result.

Comment: what do you mean sir?